# how to insert xml sub-category in php

Tags: php, xml, image

In adding an xml product feed to my site, I would also like to include the images.

This is how the xml shows the image:

```
 <images>
 <image>
 <size>
 <![CDATA[ large ]]>
 </size>
 <tag>
 <![CDATA[ default ]]>
 </tag>
 <type>
 <![CDATA[ Default image for the product ]]>
 </type>
 <location>
 <![CDATA[ https://www.website.com/image.jpeg ]]>
 </location>
 </image>
 </images>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $xml_data = simplexml_load_file("https://website.com/file.xml")
 or die("Error: Object Creation failure");
 foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data)
 {
     if (str_contains($data->category, 'shampoo')) {
      echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
        echo "<div class='item-xml'>";
            echo "<div class='title-xml'>$data->title</div>";
            echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='$data->images'></div>";
            echo "<div class='price-xml'>€ $data->price</div>";
            echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'><div class='link-xml'></div></a>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

I tried changing this line

```
            echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='$data->images'></div>";
```

into this

```
 echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='(array_values($data->images[0]->location))'></div>";
```

and this ("." instead of "->")

```
 echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='(array_values($data->images[0].location))'></div>";
```

But none works.
How can I get to the path of the image url, please?

Comment: Without a more complete XML file it's difficult to debug as we only have partial information ATM.

Comment: Here is the full XML file: https://daisycon.io/datafeed/?media_id=371617&standard_id=1&language_code=nl&locale_id=1&type=xml&program_id=5676&html_transform=none&rawdata=false&encoding=utf8&general=false

Comment: Does `echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='{$data->images->image->location}'></div>";` work?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have and images node and then an image node in that.

So for the location, you would need to reference the images and image levels, so something like

```
echo "<div class='image-xml'><img src='{$data->images->image->location}'></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not seem to work, @nigel

Comment: It's a bit unclear where your $data starts from, so try `$data->image[0]->location`

Comment: Thanks, but also doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check if it works now.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: @chechu if this has solved the problem (after updates) please mark it as accepted.